# Mapping a List of values with another List of value using Java 8

Tags: java, dictionary, java-stream

I have started programming not a long ago and I need your help. I have a List of Object1, an Object1 is composed of Item1, Item2, Item3.

I would like to group by Item2, map each Item2 with a List of Object1, then 
I would like to map each List of Object1 with a List of Item3 and then finally I would like to count the number of distinct Item3 in each List of Item3.

To say it shortly, I would like to count the number of Item3 I have per Item2 in my List of Object1.

To do that, here is what I have done so far :

```
Map<Item2, List<Object1>> object1GroupedByItem2 = object1List.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(object1->object1.getItem2()));

List<Entry<Item2, List<Object1>>> object1GroupedByItem2List = object1GroupedByItem2.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

Map<Item2, List<Item3>> item3GroupedByItem2 = object1GroupedByItem2List.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry->entry.getKey(),entry->entry.getValue().stream().map(object1->object1.getItem3()).collect(Collectors.toList())));

List<Entry<Item2, List<Item3>>> item3GroupedByItem2List = item3GroupedByItem2.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

Map<Item2, List<Item3>> distinctItem3GroupedByItem2 = item3GroupedByItem2List.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry->entry.getKey(),entry->entry.getValue().stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())));

List<Entry<Item2, List<Item3>>> distinctItem3GroupedByItem2List = distinctItem3GroupedByItem2.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

Map<Item2, Long> nbItem3PerItem2 = distinctItem3GroupedByItem2List.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry->entry.getKey(),entry->entry.getValue().stream().count());
```

I am almost sure, that there must be a better way to do the same, but I don't know how...
Can you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Edit :

```
public class Object1 {

    private Item1 item1;
    private Item2 item2;
    private Item3 item3;

    public Object1(Item1 item1, Item2 item2, Item3 item3) {
        this.item1 = item1;
        this.item2 = item2;
        this.item3 = item3;
    }

    public Item1 getItem1() {
        return item1;
    }

    public void setItem1(Item1 item1) {
        this.item1 = item1;
    }

    public Item2 getItem2() {
        return item2;
    }

    public void setItem2(Item2 item2) {
        this.item2 = item2;
    }

    public Item3 getItem3() {
        return item3;
    }

    public void setItem3(Item3 item3) {
        this.item3 = item3;
    }   
}
```

Item1, Item2 and Item3 are only wrapping a String.

As for the list of entries, how can I get rid of them? don't I need them to make my maps?

Comment: You should show us the definitions of the classes Object1, Item1, Item2 and Item3 so that we clearly understand how they related together. And you should format your code so that it is readable.

Comment: I would start by getting rid of the lists of entries.  Those are simply not necessary.

Comment: This seems like a design nightmare, you don't normally make `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, you make multiple instances of the object and store them in an array/collection. Naming is also important, the names you chose are very ambiguous and confusing (even for myself to try and track in my head)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my question :

```
Map<Item2, List<Object1>> object1GroupedByItem2 = object1List.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(object1->object1.getItem2()));

Map<Item2, Long> nbItem3PerItem2 = object1GroupedByItem2.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry->entry.getKey(), entry->entry.getValue().stream().map(object1->object.getItem3()).distinct().count()));
```

Comment: To `groupingBy` correctly, you have to implement `equals/hashCode` for your `Item2` class. Also `Item3` need `equals/hashCode` for distinct() filter